# does mergeOrUpload action on Azure Search Index takes some re-indexing time even after 200 OK response?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

We have configured Azure indexer that syncs up data between index and cosmosdb (source) for every 1 min. But we also have scenarios to update the data into index directly using nodeJS middleware and retrieve the data from the index after performing the update. We are noticing issues where the after the mergeOrUpload action on an index is performed with data shown below, we get "200" OK response but on doing GET request, azure search still returns old stale data.

1. Is there some re-index time needed? This issue is not reproducible using postman but occurs via code. We rest API approach through the code and don't use any npm modules
2. Is there a best practice or any specific API we need to use to mergeOrUpload and then the API returns us updated document?

POST functionality api: `{{url}}/indexes/orders-index/docs/index?api-version={{version}}`

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "@search.action": "mergeOrUpload",
            "productKey": "d1cef269-0059-4378-8284-df3f6a90b062",
            "aomsOrderReleaseNbr": "7640156001",
            "aomsOrderEntryDate": "2018-05-29T00:00:00Z",
            "supplierNbr": "SWM",
            "locationName": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

GET functionality api: `{{url}}/indexes/orders-index/docs?api-version={{version}}&$count=true&search=lowerProductKey:/.*d1cef269\-0059\-4378\-8284\-df3f6a90b062.*/&queryType=full&$top=100&$skip=0`

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://abcd/indexes('orders-index')/$metadata#docs",
    "@odata.count": 1,
    "value": [
        {
            "@search.score": 1,
            "productKey": "d1cef269-0059-4378-8284-df3f6a90b062",
            "aomsOrderReleaseNbr": "7640156001",
            "aomsOrderEntryDate": "2018-05-29T00:00:00Z",
            "supplierNbr": "SWM",
            "locationName": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Azure search uses a distributed write (quorum-based) mechanism to ensure that data persisted to the index is available. Due to this, the data in the index will be **eventually consistent**, but if you query the index soon after you have inserted documents into the index (via POST) the newly inserted documents might not immediately show up. **This is a deliberate decision to optimize query performance.**

**Please note that when an indexer run is successful, or the insert into index API returns 200 OK, it doesn't mean that the documents are immediately available for searching.** 200 does mean the documents are persisted in durable storage though.

The delay in the documents showing up in your search results depends on a number of factors, some of which are

1. How much load your service is under
2. The number of replicas of your search service
3. The number of documents you have inserted

Regarding this:

> We have configured Azure indexer that syncs up data between index and cosmosdb (source) for every 1 min. But we also have scenarios to update the data into index directly using nodeJS middleware and retrieve the data from the index after performing the update

Firstly, your azure search indexer cannot have a schedule of under 5 minutes, so I am curious how it is every minute.
Anyway, because you have an indexer as well as a custom job that writes to the same index, if they happen to "index" the same document (based on the document key) - the last writer wins; this could also cause potentially stale results to show up, depending on if there are other content differences in the two documents.

Regarding best practices:

1. We recommend not having your query rely on strong consistency guarantees as much as possible -- i.e., your application should be ok with dealing with queries that return slightly stale data.
2. Try to incorporate some delay (which as I said cannot be determined, but needs to be experimented with) between the indexing operation and the query operation.
3. If you can somehow determine that documents returned by the query are stale, you could also incorporate some sort of retries (with a reasonable sleep interval between them)

Comment: We have created custom run indexer endpoint as a daemon service to run every 1 min. But ideally, you should at least provide etag support. Is etag support planned any time soon?

Comment: So I take it that when you said indexer, you are referring to a custom indexer.
Azure search has an indexer which can crawl through your data and make incremental progress, if you use a data change detection policy + set up a schedule.

You can find more details about that here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-overview

Comment: Hi Aravind, We have a requirement to retrieve data from the index without any delay, hence we 1) Stopped OOTB indexer that runs every 5 mins (we configured this initially) 2) Configured an indexer that runs every 1 min using cronjob using nodejs middleware 3) Update document to index and cosmosdb simultaneously as we run reports against the index. But I think at least providing etag support should have helped us. Is there ETA against ETag support?

Comment: The indexer mechanism is our recommended way for incrementally adding data from data sources to the index. Could you clarify what support you want against ETags? Please feel free to elaborate your request on our user voice here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search

Comment: There is no ETags support for documents planned at this point. Please vote for it on UserVoice.